# How to show recent search history list in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-sqlite

I have an activity 'A' which has a AutoCompleteTextView where I have implemented the suggestions. On clicking the suggestions I am starting a new activity 'B' which gives the result. I want to implement a recent search history list below the AutoCompleteTextView in activity 'A'. The list keeps on increasing upto a certain NO. How do I do it? Help please!!

Comment: use `SharedPreferences` or `Database` to store history

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1/ Create an SQLite Database.

2/ Store each new searches

3/ Perform a SELECT query to retrieve the previous searches and then put them into the adapter of your AutoCompleteTextView to display the suggestion list

**EDIT:**

*For step 1:*

```
CREATE TABLE searches(
   id INTEGER  PRIMARY KEY   AUTOINCREMENT,
   search TEXT,
   date INTEGER, => could be helpful
);
```

*For step 2:*

```
INSERT INTO searches (search, date) VALUES (myValue, theCurrentDate);
```

*For step 3:*

```
SELECT * FROM searches ORDER BY search;
```

OR

```
SELECT * FROM searches ORDER BY date;
```

Hope it helps